# Calling function from parent class in child instance [javascript]

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance

I need to call functions from a parent class via the instances of the child class.

```js
class A {
  function A1() 
  function A2()
  function A3()  
}
class B extends A {
  function B1()  
  function B2()
}

const X = new B();
X.A1();
```

Above is a sample pseudocode.

How should I go about this?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. `function() { .. }`s should not be right inside a `class` block, did you mean to use methods instead? eg `A1() {`. If you fix that, your code should work just fine as is

Comment: @CertainPerformance OP mentioned that the code is pseudocode.

Comment: Best to only put *runnable* code as a live code snippet. Fixing the syntax still achieves his desired result, though

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just a bit of fixing of your pseudocode, the following will work for what you want. Functions within a class aren't declared with the `function` keyword.

```js
class A {
  A1 () { console.log('A1') }
}

class B extends A {
  B1 () { }
}

let x = new B()
x.A1()
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your pseudocode is translated into valid JavaScript syntax, your code will work:

```js
class A {
  A1() {
    console.log("A1");
  }
  A2() {
    console.log("A2");
  }
  A3() {
    console.log("A3");
  }
}
class B extends A {
  B1() {
    console.log("B1");
  }
  B2() {
    console.log("B2");
  }
}

const X = new B();
X.A1();
X.B2();
```